# C# Ping-Class - cancel Ping.Send() if connection error

Tags: c#, excel, server, ping, hostname

i built a simple program that takes an excel list containing a set of server host names and pinging each one of these returning the results in the console how many of the hosts are online.

I am using a try/catch block to prevent the app from crashing when the hostname is unknown (upon connection error).

Now i am looking for a solution to skip the ping request upon connection error, so the program continues to ping the next hostname in line and the program can finish faster without waiting for the exception to happen.

Thats the code i am using right now.

```
foreach (var server in serverList)
{        
     try
     {
         var reply = pingSender.Send(server, 1000);              

         //if server is reachable
         if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
         {
             //add server to new excel and display it as online
             onlineList.Cells[serverCount, 1] = server + " is online";
             //increase counters
             serverCount++;
             onlineCount++;
         }
         else
         {
             //add server to new excel and display it as offline
             onlineList.Cells[serverCount, 2] = server + " is offline or unreachable.";                        
             serverCount++;
         } 
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         //if in any case the destination is unknown and prevent application from crashing
         onlineList.Cells[serverCount, 2] = server + " is offline or unreachable.";
         serverCount++;             
     }       
 }
```

Comment: Using `continue` in the catch block is not necessary since the catch block is the last part of the foreach loop anyway

Comment: the code is correct.. you are catching the exception in the loop. so if it gets caught, the next server will be pinged. in the catch , the continue isn't necessary at all. you don't have any other logic after that line, so it will continue with the next element in your list

Comment: A little code review. Using `Convert.ToInt32` when a simple cast would do isn't great. Better would be to avoid floating point all together: `serverList.Coun() * 65 /100`. Best would be to check a range around the target value (there may be no value of `serverCount` that matches exactly. Eg. if 50 servers, you'll never see the 25% step).

Comment: thanks for all the reviews of my code - i started progamming only a few weeks ago, so i know my code is far from clean and optimal. im trying to clean it up upon your recommendations. the thing is, im trying to make my program finish faster, so i dont have to wait for the catch block to trigger, but instead cancel the ping.send() attempt before. i hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Richard thanks for your answer, i cleaned it up and got rid of the convert method. the thing is, ive defined a progress range before, but then the console keeps writing the "...%" in every iteration of the foreach loop - so i ended up with something like "...15%...15%...15%..." as long as the servercount is in the specific range.

Comment: @Stefan Let me know if the answer worked :-)

Comment: The only two solutions I see are 1) reduce the timeout you specify (currently 1000ms) and/or 2) parallelize processing of the list so that the hosts are not pinged one after the other but multiple pings are processed in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you perform the ping sequentially, one after the other. Improve performance by having multiple threads run in parallel to perform the pinging like in this sample code.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Make a list of host names to ping
    List<string> hostnames = new List<string>();

    // Use local hostnames a .. z. 
    // and domain names a.com .. z.com
    for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
    {
        hostnames.Add(c.ToString());
        hostnames.Add("www." + c + ".com");
    }

    // Use some well known hostnames
    hostnames.Add("www.google.com");
    hostnames.Add("www.microsoft.com");
    hostnames.Add("www.apple.com");

    // Ping the hostnames and get the results as a dictionary
    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, bool> results = await Task.Run(() => PingHosts(hostnames));

    // Output the content of the results, note that the order 
    // is not the same as in the original list of
    // hostnames because of parallel processing
    foreach(var result in results)
    {
        if(result.Value)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText("Ping to " + result.Key + ": OK" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.AppendText("Ping to " + result.Key + ": ERROR" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}

// This function will ping a single host and return true or false
// based on whether it can be pinged
private bool PingSingleHost(string hostname)
{
    try
    {
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        var reply = ping.Send(hostname, 1000);
        bool wasSuccessful = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
        return wasSuccessful;
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// Ping the given list of hostnames and return their status
// (can they be pinged) as a dictionary where the Key is the hostname
// and the value is a boolean with the ping result
private IReadOnlyDictionary<string, bool> PingHosts(IEnumerable<string> hostnames)
{
    // Use 30 parallel worker threads
    // This number can be quite high because the
    // workers will spend most time waiting 
    // for an answer
    int numberOfWorkers = 30;

    // Place the hosts into a queue
    ConcurrentQueue<string> jobsQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(hostnames);

    // Use a concurrent dictionary to store the results
    // The concurrent dictionary will automatically handle
    // multiple threads accessing the dictionary at the same time
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool> results = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool>();

    // Worker function which keeps reading new hostnames from the given jobsQueue
    // and pings those hostnames and writes the result to the given results dictionary
    // until the queue is empty
    ThreadStart Worker = () =>
    {
        string hostname;

        // While the job queue is not empty, get a host from the queue
        while(jobsQueue.TryDequeue(out hostname))
        {
            // Ping the host and 
            bool wasSuccessful = PingSingleHost(hostname);

            // write the result to results dictionary
            results.TryAdd(hostname, wasSuccessful);
        }
    };


    // Start the Worker threads
    List<Thread> workers = new List<Thread>();

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfWorkers; i++)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(Worker);
        thread.Start();
        workers.Add(thread);
    }

    // Wait for all workers to have finished
    foreach(var thread in workers)
    {
        thread.Join();
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: using multi threads totaly makes sense! thanks for your answer. i will consider this and try to implement it.

Comment: I should add that using explicit threads as in this code results in much better performance compared to using asynchronous/await or the TPL